# EJB - Transaction Time out

Tags: java, transactions, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

How can we define method level transaction timeout in Session EJB (Container Managed Transaction) in JBOSS 4 container?

Answer (score 4):

This is excerpt from [JBoss Wiki](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/TransactionTimeout) which specifies exactly this:

> Per-method basis: Modifying the
>    element inside
>   the  element of a session or
>   entity bean. This is located in the
>   META-INF/jboss.xml deployment
>   descriptor of a session bean. When the
>   transaction timeout is specified at
>   the method level, it overrides the
>   default timeout. Further information
>   about this element can be found in
>   jboss-x.x.x/docs/dtd/jboss_4_0.dtd.
>   Example taken from the testsuite:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss>
  <enterprise-beans>
    <session>
      <ejb-name>TxTimeout</ejb-name>
      <jndi-name>jbosstest/tm/TxTimeout</jndi-name>
      <exception-on-rollback>true</exception-on-rollback>
      <method-attributes>
        <method>
          <method-name>testOverriddenTimeoutExpires</method-name>
          <transaction-timeout>5</transaction-timeout>
        </method>
        <method>
          <method-name>testOverriddenTimeoutDoesNotExpire</method-name>
          <transaction-timeout>20</transaction-timeout>
        </method>
      </method-attributes>
    </session>
  </enterprise-beans>    
</jboss>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

http://shrubbery.homeip.net/wiki/Session,_EJB_and_Conversation_Timeouts

[Domain name changed by the author]

Comment: Unfortunately this link doesn't provide info on transactions timeout settings. It's specify settings for TTL for HttpSession/Statefull Beans

Comment: @Oleg Iavorskyi tnx for that info

Comment: The link should be http://shrubbery.homeip.net/wiki/Session,_EJB_and_Conversation_Timeouts

Comment: Incorrect link. Avoid providing links to answer a question.