# EJB CMT and transaction timeout

Tags: transactions, ejb, ejb-2.x

In a Websphere7 environment, the container is set to timeout any transaction that last longer than 120 seconds for all of our CMT Session Beans.

However, I've been ask to add a feature in one of our EJB, and the time to proceed it will be larger than this timeout (around 20 minutes). As this is a one-shot feature, I really don't want to increase the transaction timeout, as it will impact all other beans.

Is it possible to declare that one method in a bean, or a specific session bean, has it's own timeout delay ?

If that's not possible, I suppose my only solution is to create a CMT bean ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know websphere7, for Jboss you have something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155874/ejb-transaction-time-out) and maybe you will find something similar for websphere7. If not, in my opinion, you have 3 options.

1. Re-architecture your solution to use MDB's for long running tasks to execute them asynchronously
2. User [UserTransaction](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html) and setTransactionTimeout to set the transaction timeout for the specific transaction
3. Create a separate CMT bean with exclusive transaction timeout specified in xml for this functionality

Comment: I would be interested to see how to apply solution 3

Comment: Interesting, I thought it would be as easy as it is in jboss/weblogic but apparently its not :). Anyways, I have found smth which might help: http://docs.jboss.org/seam/snapshot/en-US/html/websphere.html - look into section: 40.4. Configuring timeouts for Stateful Session Beans